# How to intercept request with mitmproxy before response is streamed?

Tags: python, request, mitmproxy

The request I am trying to intercept and modify is a get request with only one parameter and I try to modify it:

```
from mitmproxy import http

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.pretty_url.startswith(BASE_URL):
        flow.request.url = BASE_URL.replace('abc', 'def')
```

The above shows what I am trying to do in a nutshell. But unfortunately, according to [docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/api/events.html#HTTPEvents.request),

> this event fires after the entire body has been streamed.

In the end, I am not able to modify the request. Am I missing something here? Because if modify requests is not possible, then what is the point of mitmproxy?

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about mitmproxy and nothing about its event model but it might be telling you that you have to intercept *the entire body first* (perhaps by responding to an appropriate event *before* this event is fired) and then you can modify it when responding to this event.

Comment: What is `BASE_URL`? You check against `BASE_URL`  then modify `BASE_URL` for use in the redirect which seems weird.

Comment: It is a misunderstanding on your side: each request has a body and each response has a body, too. When a GET request is intercepted the request body is empty.

Comment: BASE_URL is not important. @Robert, the thing is that when this request is "intercepted", it already has response

Comment: Have you enabled streaming via options? Better do so individually per request: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-features/#streaming

Comment: @Tugay BASE_URL is important - I'm using mitmproxy in a very similar way to alter URL and it works for me just fine. Have you checked whether your `if` is true when you expect it to be? It's hard to help you, when we cannot see the full code. Also, make sure your request is NOT streamed as such requests cannot be modified, AFAIR.